# Passing function from one sibling to another (the 2020 way)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components

Recently I started working with Angular and I'm currently working on a simple dashboard.

I have a component "layout" which has all the other components imported which are "filter" and "table" between some other. My table component looks very similar to the Angular example (https://stackblitz.com/angular/xbgqqdajbax?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filtering-example.html) but there the filter is included in the component. I want it to be separate to use it also elsewhere.

This is my filter component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-filter',
    templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
    styles: [],
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
    value = ''

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

filter template

```
    <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
    <input
        matInput
        (keyup)="applyFilter($event)"
        placeholder="Ex. ium"
        #input
    />
</mat-form-field>
```

table component and table template are like the ones on stackblitz.

layout template

```
<div>
    <app-nav></app-nav>

    <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100">
        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]="4"
            [rowspan]="1"
            [ngStyle]="{ background: 'lightgreen' }"
        >
            <app-datepicker></app-datepicker>
        </mat-grid-tile>

        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]="4"
            [rowspan]="1"
            [ngStyle]="{ background: 'lightblue' }"
        >
            <app-filter></app-filter
        ></mat-grid-tile>

        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]="4"
            [rowspan]="7"
            [ngStyle]="{ background: 'lightpink' }"
        >
            <app-table></app-table
        ></mat-grid-tile>

        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]="4"
            [rowspan]="3"
            [ngStyle]="{ background: '#DDBDF1' }"
        >
            4</mat-grid-tile
        >
    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

layout component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-layout',
    templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
    styles: [
        `
            app-table {
                width: 90%;
            }
        `,
    ],
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

I read about rxjs, child > parent, parent > child, etc but I couldn't find anything explaining how to do it with a function. So I could technically pass a string from one component to another but it didn't worked for a function in a template.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please add the code where you use the ```filter``` and ```template``` components together, since it makes answering easier.

Comment: you can see it in the layout template. "app-filter" and "app-table". If you meant that

Comment: correct, did not see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to keep things seperated, I would suggest the following approach:

In your `filter.component.ts` emit an event when the filter value changes

```js
@Output() onValueChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

you fire this event in your `filter.component.html`. Or idealy you could also throttle it and fire it within your filter component somewhere when e.g. the text did not change after 100ms (to avoid firing to many events)

```html
(keyup)="onValueChanged.emit(currentValue)"
```

In your `layout` component you can listen to the event and trigger the table filter mechanism.

```html
<app-filter (onValueChanged)="table.applyFilter($event)"></app-filter>
<app-table #table></app-table>
```

In your table you then have to implemente the `applyFilter` function

Comment: Thank you. First it didn't work but that was because I passed the value and applyFilter was looking for a event but now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the filter component template you can add

```
<input type="text" (change)=changeFilter($event)>
```

Then inside the Filter component add

```
@Output() filterChanged = new EventEmitter();
changeFilter(changeEvent) { this.filterChanged.emit(changeEvent.target.value)}
```

In the Layout element you can then access the Output by using

```
<app-filter (filterChanged)=setNewFilter($event)></app-filter>
```

and in the Layout component access the new Filter value like

```
filter: string = '';
setNewFilter(newFilter: string) { this.filter = newFilter }
```

And at last pass the filter into the table element as expected:

```
<app-table [filter]="filter"></app-table>
```

Which can be used inside the app-Table component via input

```
@Input() filter = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Filter component as child to any other component, as you have used here in side Layout component ->

You can use Output event emitter inside the filter.component.ts
@Output Eventemitter to pass the output string from filter component to any other component.

And in layout or any other component watch the output emitter
Html :

```
<app-filter (eventChange)="outputString($event)"></app-filter>
```

ts : `outputString(event: string) { console.log('Output String',event) }`